# movy files that contain string or start with string

Tags: file, batch-file, file-io, copy, xcopy

I'm looking to move .txt files from a folder containing many .txt files.

But only .txt files that start with string  'settlement-id' or contains 'settlement-id'.

Preferably a .bat file.

Comment: `move *settlement-id*.txt \destination`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b/a-d ^| find /i "settlement-id") do copy "%%a" "YOUR_PATH"
```